# Is it possible to insert image in gedit in Linux?

Tags: linux, rhel, gedit

I'm using RHEL. I want to insert an image in `gedit`, but I'm not able to do so. Also I'm unable to install LibreOffice because they are asking for a subscription. Any alternate to `gedit` or can we insert image in `gedit`.

Comment: No, you need Emacs for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `gedit` is strictly a text editor, and does not provide a method for inserting images or embedding images within its files.

I think you're getting confused on the subscription details. The subscription is probably because you're using RHEL, LibreOffice is a free product, you can download the RPMs directly from the project's website and install them manually.

See this page for the RPMs.

- http://www.libreoffice.org/download/?version=4.1.4&lang=en-US&type=rpm-x86_64

#### Downloading & Installation

Take a look at the extensive documentation that already exists on the LibreOffice website. It'll take you through the various installation steps.

- https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Installing_LibreOffice_on_Linux

Comment: You know that I'm new to linux. Can you provide me installation guide for libreoffice rpm ?

Comment: The portable one is for Windows. OP will need Wine?

Comment: @vasa1 - thanks, missed that, removed it.